# How to row sum with factors in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have data like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("001", "002", "003", "004"),
                 banana = c("banana", NA, NA, NA),
                 apple = c(NA, "apple", "apple", NA),
                 orange = c("orange", NA, NA, NA),
                 mango = c(NA, NA, NA, "mango"))

 id banana apple orange mango
001 banana    NA orange    NA
002     NA apple     NA    NA
003     NA apple     NA    NA
004     NA    NA     NA mango
```

I'd like to consolidate the variables into a variable `flavor` in the following manner:

```
 id banana apple orange mango flavor
001 banana    NA orange    NA  mixed
002     NA apple     NA    NA  apple
003     NA apple     NA    NA  apple
004     NA    NA     NA mango  mango
```

How do I do this? Any help is appreciated, although a generalisable `dplyr` solution would be great.

Edit: I need a solution robust to having other columns in my dataframe too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have requested, here's a `dplyr` solution.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  mutate(flavor = ifelse(sum(is.na(value)) == ncol(df) - 2, value[!is.na(value)], "mixed"), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  relocate(-flavor) # move the flavor column to the last

# A tibble: 4 × 6
  id    banana apple orange mango flavor
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> 
1 001   banana NA    orange NA    mixed 
2 002   NA     apple NA     NA    apple 
3 003   NA     apple NA     NA    apple 
4 004   NA     NA    NA     mango mango
```

Comment: How to specify which columns I want? Because I have other columns in my df, I want to specify the sum to be done over `banana:mango`

Comment: I admit the situation will become more complex if you have more columns than your example, but you can specify the columns in `pivot_longer`. i.e. `pivot_longer(banana:mango)`.

Comment: What does `ncol(df) - 2` do in your code?

Comment: From banana to mango, you have four columns to compare. If you only have one unique fruit, you get three `NA` (4 columns - 1 unique fruit = 3), `ncol(df) - 2` gives 3, therefore it tells which rows only have one fruit (if there're mixed fruits, the number of `NA` would be less than three). I hope I make myself clear.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the unique count is more than one:

```
df$flavor <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(i)
                   ifelse(length(unique(na.omit(i))) > 1, "mixed", unique(na.omit(i))))

df$flavor
# [1] "mixed" "apple" "apple" "mango"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your problem as follow:

```
# Using built-in functions
df$flavor = ifelse(rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))>1, "mixed", do.call(pmin, c(df[-1], na.rm=T)))

# Using dplyr

library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(flavor = if_else(rowSums(!is.na(pick(-id)))>1, "mixed", do.call(coalesce, pick(-id))))

# Using data.table

library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, flavor := fifelse(rowSums(!is.na(.SD))>1, "mixed", fcoalesce(.SD)), .SDcols=!"id"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("001", "002", "003", "004"),
                 banana = c("banana", NA, NA, NA),
                 apple = c(NA, "apple", "apple", NA),
                 orange = c("orange", NA, NA, NA),
                 mango = c(NA, NA, NA, "mango"))

library(tidyverse)

my_labeller <- function(x){
nax <- na.omit(x)
case_when(length(nax)>1L ~ 'mixed',
          length(nax)==1L ~ nax,
          .default = NA_character_) |> unique()
}


(flav_set <- pivot_longer(df,cols=-id,
             names_to = "column",
             values_to = "entries") |>
  select(-column) |>
  summarise(flavour=my_labeller(entries),.by=id) )

(result <- left_join(df,
                    flav_set))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have four columns to compare, we can `sum` the `NA` values of each row. If that equals 3, it means we only have one unique value, otherwise it's mixed.

```r
apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) == ncol(df) - 2, na.omit(x), "mixed"))
[1] "mixed" "apple" "apple" "mango"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Create a simple auxiliary function, `flavor` and then apply it to each row.

```
library(dplyr)

flavor <- function(x, y = na.omit(unlist(x)) ) {
  if (length(y) == 1) y else if (length(y) > 1) "mixed" else NA
}

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(flavor = flavor(pick(-1))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  id    banana apple orange mango flavor
  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> 
1 001   banana <NA>  orange <NA>  mixed 
2 002   <NA>   apple <NA>   <NA>  apple 
3 003   <NA>   apple <NA>   <NA>  apple 
4 004   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   mango mango
```

**2)** Another possibility is to collapse all non-NA elements in each row using `toString` and then replace any result with a comma with `mixed`.  If a row is all NA this one produces a result of "" for that
row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(flavor = toString(na.omit(unlist(pick(-1)))),
         flavor = if_else(grepl(",", flavor), "mixed", flavor)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
idx <- !is.na(df[-1])
df$flavor <- ifelse(rowSums(idx) > 1, "mixed", names(df[-1])[max.col(idx)])
```

which gives

```
> df
   id banana apple orange mango flavor
1 001 banana  <NA> orange  <NA>  mixed
2 002   <NA> apple   <NA>  <NA>  apple
3 003   <NA> apple   <NA>  <NA>  apple
4 004   <NA>  <NA>   <NA> mango  mango
```